# how to know which line of jar file error out while running it in jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv

i am executing some jar file in my tibco process deployed on jboss server. so my question is if any of the jar file errors out how can i know which line or method of the jar file errored out?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is exceptionally vague, but in general, errors in Java are handled using Exceptions, so you should look at your log files for a stacktrace which will give you all of the class and line information about where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If the jar has source code attached then you could find out exactly where the error lies.

JARs themselves have exception handling setup, which then prints the Error messages.